# Missing alias when overriding table name

Tags: peewee

When I override the table name in a models meta class, queries are generated with an alias however the `AS` keyword is not implemented unless I specify the alias.

for example:

```
class SomeModel(SomeBaseModel):
    name = TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'some_model'
        # Queries use an alias without declaring it unless specified below.
        table_alias = 'some_model'
```

In peewee v2.7.4, what can be done to avoid manually supplying an alias?

Comment: You are using a very old version of Peewee. Strongly recommend upgrading.

Comment: I don't have a choice, its bundled in an constrained platform that I don't have that level of control on, otherwise that would have been my first step.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of the problem you're experiencing, or what you're trying to accomplish? I don't understand.

Comment: I created a complete portable repro and it works with or without the table_alias. The only difference in the environment versus my repro is the placement of the code and a helper method to generate the database path (however that vendor code molests the builtins). I am at a loss as to what the issue is and how the behavior can vary...